# How can I turn a transparant background visible again in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, background, label, transparency

I'm using Python Tkinter `my_label.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")` to turn the backgorund of a new pop-up label transparent and `my_label.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "grey")` to make it visible again. This works because I have a white background with black letters on it.
But this seems a little greedy to me.
Is there a different way of turning the background visible again?

Comment: Have you tried using: `.attributes("-transparentcolor", "none")`?

Comment: When using `my_label.master.attributes("-transparentcolor", "none")` it results in an error: unknown color name "none"

Comment: From [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M14) it would be reasonable to try `.attributes("-transparentcolor", "")`

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. The trick is to google it (it didn't work). If that doesn't help, look at the documentation. I was looking at that page a few hours ago and still had it open.

Comment: Can I somehow add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [tcl's documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M14): *If the empty string is specified (default), no transparent color is used.*

That means that you can use `.attributes("-transparentcolor", "")` to reset the transparent colour of the window.